# Invalid array or Invalid integer in using Stripe "unit_amount"

Tags: php, symfony, stripe-payments, payment

I have a problem when I want to integer Stripe on my project in Symfony.
I use Stripe v.9.5.0 and I have different errors when I implement "unit_amount" for Stripe

I have an OrderController:

```
$product_for_stripe = [];
$YOUR_DOMAIN = 'https://localhost:8000/';

//Enregister sur mon entity Order_details

foreach ($cart->getFull() as $product) {
    $orderDetails = new OrderDetails();
    $orderDetails->setMyOrder($order);
    $orderDetails->setProduct($product['product']);
    $orderDetails->setQuantity($product['quantity']);
    $orderDetails->setPrice($product['product']->getPrix());
    $orderDetails->setTotal($product['product']->getPrix() * $product['quantity']);
    $this->entityManager->persist($orderDetails);

    $product_for_stripe[] = [
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => 'eur',
            'product_data' => [
                'name' => $product['product']->getName(),
                'images' => $product['product']->getImage()
             ],
            'unit_amount' => $orderDetails->getPrice(),
        ],
        'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
    ];

}


//$this->entityManager->flush();
Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51LiLoMDGYOFHKYepnY3xMBT5vwMJWH2XR3ntN9GpHXYtapN29AvQVty21GPUx0qVa2J6MWFr69ke3Yq1p3MJL1yV00kCU59YvE');

$checkout_session = Session::create([
    'line_items' =>
        [$product_for_stripe],
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html',
    'cancel_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/cancel.html',
]);

dump($checkout_session->id);
dd($checkout_session);
```

When I want to debug $checkout_session I have this error:

```
"Invalid integer: 532.46"
```

I have tried `round($orderDetails->getPrice())` for `unit_amount` and I have this error:

```
"Invalid array"
```

I'm blocked, it's a project for my degree in school, if somebody can help me and have a solution , I would be happy.

Answer (score 1):

[`unit_amount`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-unit_amount) should be a non-negative integer in a [currency’s smallest unit](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal) also called as minor unit.

For example, EUR's smallest unit is cents. EUR 10 is equivalent to 1000 cents. In Checkout Session creation request, `unit_amount` will then be set to `1000` with `currency='eur'`.

Comment: thank you for your response. But I have not understand. For Example my price is $orderDetails->getPrice() and when I write $orderDetails->getPrice()*100 for to have 53246 (cents) I have this error -> "Invalid array"

Comment: I finally have fix to bug, the problem is not unit_amount but "'images' => $product['product']->getImage()" who shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method as it will help you to use the decimal value as the amount and display the same amount in the invoice and during payment.

```
amount: Math.round(49.99 * 100)
```